# .bashrc not run on login

Tags: bash, bashrc

I have been playing with colorized prompts, set in `.bashrc`.

The problem is I always need to source the `.bashrc` *after* logging in.  When I log in, I can see the file is sourced (I tried adding an `echo "SOURCED"` at top of the file.

Yet when I login, the commands for colored prompts never run, although re-sourcing `.bashrc` works - colors are set after `source ~/.bashrc`, I am curious as to the nature of this behavior.

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTFILESIZE=1000000
HISTSIZE=1000000

# Ignore commands that start with a space, and duplicates
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# Ignore certain commands
HISTIGNORE='ls:bg:fg:history'

# Timestamp commands
HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '

# One commands per line
shopt -s cmdhist

# Save commands to history immediately
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'


# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac



# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
        # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
        # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
        # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes
    else
        color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1=`echo -ne "$HOST_COLOR\H\[\033[00m\]\[\e[$COLON_COLOR\]:\[\033[01;32m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\\[\033[01;33m\]\$\[\033[00m\] "`
   # PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\H\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

# Add bin to path
PATH="${PATH:+${PATH}:}$HOME/bin"

# Color the colon red if root
COLON_COLOR='0m'
if [ ${UID} -eq 0 ]; then
    COLON_COLOR='1;31m'
fi
```

Comment: How are you logging in? SSH? You [said](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023682/bashrc-not-run-on-login#comment1662743_1023687) `echo "TEST"` at the top of `.bashrc` prints `TEST` so it seems `.bashrc` *is* being sourced. What happens if you instead put it just below the `esac` line? This will check for the (admittedly small) possibility that your login shell is somehow noninteractive (which could happen if you're logging in with some unusual method). Please **[edit]** with this information and also the contents of all of `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, and `~/.bash_login` that exist. Thanks!

Comment: I had the same issue at my new work. my profile wasn't loaded at login, but if i did a su to my user, then it was loaded. 
Turned out the creator of my user forgot to add a shell, so check /etc/passwd for details on your user.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do you have `.profile` or a `.bash_profile`?

When BASH is invoked as a login shell, the following scripts are executed:

1. `/etc/profile`
2. `~/.bash_profile`
3. `~/.bash_login`
4. `~/.profile`

I have the following in my `~/.profile` to invoke `.bashrc`:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Yes, indeed I do.  I think it is sourced at login, because setting `echo "TEST"` at top of .bashrc  get printed out when I log in.

Comment: I don't see that echo "TEST" in the source above.  Just out of curiosity, is that before or after the interactive test?

Comment: Doesn't the shell attempt to run the scripts you list, but stop after it finds the first one? e.g. if I have a `~/.bash_login`, then it does not run `~/.profile`...